# Enforce size of array in the input of a function

Tags: c++

I have a class with an array with a specific size:

```
class foo {
    int myarray[6];
    foo();
}

foo::foo(int *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        myarray[i] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid error if array is less then the size of myarray or a way to prevent memory access error?

Comment: Not if you just pass a simple pointer. Either pass the size of the input as another argument or use a more modern approach, like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Change `int myarray[6];` to `std::array<int, 6> myarray`;  Or just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think OP is asking about the size of the `array` argument.

Comment: @AdrianMole - agreed solution is to stop using c-arrays.

Comment: I think your constructor declaration should match the definition of `foo::foo(int* array))`.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that each position in the array has a valid value associated with it?

Answer (score 4):

You can force a size by taking the array by reference.  Since the size of an array is part of it's type, using

```
foo::foo(int (&array)[6])
```

forces the caller to give the function a `int[6]` as no other `int[N]` can bind to the reference.